# jquery ui sortable, bootstrap accordion, .panel-heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I move sortable element to closed panels (dropping on `.panel-heading`)?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yaroslaw/jsgh2xvk/

```
$(".table-tags tbody").sortable({
    connectWith: ".table-tags tbody",
    items: "> tr",
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Could you specify your question some more? I am not a hundred percent sure what it is that you are trying to obtain? Do you want the panel to open when you hover it and then be able to drop it. Or do you want to be able to drop it on top of the closed list (which then adds it to the list)?

Comment: I want to drop it on top of the closed list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have first now have time to look at it.

I hope this is what you wanted. At least this is how I think it should work from your description.

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsgh2xvk/6/)

I added some javascript from another answer here on stackoverflow to detect if the element is hovering a title. If the element is hovering a title of a closed list then we open that list which makes you able to drop the element in that list. If you have questions to the code. Don't hesitate to ask.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title collapse-link">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover border-bottom table-tags">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th class="text-right">Przypisani agenci</th>
            <th class="text-right">Usuń tag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 1 - tag 1</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">25</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 1 - tag 2</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">19</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title collapse-link">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover border-bottom table-tags">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th class="text-right">Przypisani agenci</th>
            <th class="text-right">Usuń tag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 2 - tag 1</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">25</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 2 - tag 2</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">19</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
    <h4 class="panel-title collapse-link">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover border-bottom table-tags">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th class="text-right">Przypisani agenci</th>
            <th class="text-right">Usuń tag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 3 - tag 1</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">25</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-info label-big">panel 3 - tag 2</span></td>
            <td class="text-right">19</td>
            <td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="tag-remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tag
      Przypisani agenci
      Usuń tag
    
  
  
    
      outside - tag 1
      25
      
    
    
      outside - tag 2
      19

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $links = $('.collapse-link a');

// remove tag
$('body').on('click', '.tag-remove', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
})

// drag/drop tags
$(".table-tags tbody").sortable({
    appendTo: document.body,
  connectWith: ".table-tags tbody",
  items: "> tr",
  start: function(event, ui) {
    var draggedItem = ui.helper;
    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
      moved(e, draggedItem);
    });
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(window).unbind("mousemove");
  },
  helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

//Code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298712/jquery-ui-sortable-determine-which-element-is-beneath-the-element-being-dragge
function moved(e, draggedItem) {
  //Dragged item's position++
  var dpos = draggedItem.position();
  var d = {
    top: dpos.top,
    bottom:    dpos.top + draggedItem.height(),
    left: dpos.left,
    right: dpos.left + draggedItem.width()
  };

  //Find sortable elements (li's) covered by draggedItem
  var hoveredOver = $links.not(draggedItem).filter(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var pos = t.position();

    //This li's position++
    var p = {
      top: pos.top,
      bottom:    pos.top + t.height(),
      left: pos.left,
      right: pos.left + t.width()
    };

    //itc = intersect
    var itcTop         = p.top <= d.bottom;
    var itcBtm         = d.top <= p.bottom;
    var itcLeft     = p.left <= d.right;
    var itcRight     = d.left <= p.right;

    return itcTop && itcBtm && itcLeft && itcRight;
  });

    if(hoveredOver && hoveredOver.hasClass('collapsed')){
    hoveredOver.click();
  }
};
```